# Find combination that gives maximum profit

Tags: algorithm

Say I have table that looks like this:

ID | Cost | Profit

1 | 0.55 | 1.24

2 | 0.23 | 3.11

3 | 0.19 | 2.21

4 | 0.53 | 1.49

... and so on.

How do I find the maximum profit if my budget is of certain value? ie: Find max profit with cost of 1.12. If from the table above, I should take item from ID 2  + 3 + 4 to maximize my profit.

I'm trying to google something from LP, Operation Research but I'm really Googling blindly, I don't know what are the keywords I should look for. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [0/1 Knapsack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-problem/)! I have assumed from the example you gave that you need to take the item as a whole and not a fraction of the item. Otherwise go for default (Fractional) Knapsack.

Get to know about the [greedy version of solution & why it might fail](http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/greedy.html), then the Fractional Knapsack Dynamic Programming style of solution for this problem and then 0/1 Knapsack! This is how you should learn to solve this problem.

Let me know if you need anything else on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `O(2n + sort)` algorithm that should produce good results in most cases

1. Calculate yield for each item (`item.yield = item.profit / item.cost`)
2. Sort items by yield (highest yield first)
3. Iterate over sorted items whilst `remaining_budget > 0`
4. Purchase `number_of_items = floor(remaining_budget / item.cost)` of `item.id`, subtract `number_of_items * item.cost` from `remaining_cost`

It won't always catch all edge cases if you are operating discretely, e.g. say you have `budget = 100`, and an item `A` with `cost = 51, yield = 1.5` and another item `B` with `cost = 50, yield = 1.4`,

- `100 - 51 = 49` + `51 * 1.5 = 76.5` = `125`,
  One `A` results in `25.5` profit
- `100 - 2 * 50 = 0` + `2 *` `50 * 1.4 = 70` = `140`,
  Two `B`s result in `40` profit,
  i.e. buying two individually worse ones is better due to using the entirety of the budget more efficiently

But if you're operating continuously it will begin to pick up performance gains as the budget stops being a restricting factor

---

Optimisations may include

- Calculate yield at sort time, one less iteration over the entire data structure
- Removing the sort step and instead "throwing away" worse choices as you iterate through, this can end up taking a lot longer to complete
- Ending the iteration when `remaining_budget < minumum_unit_cost`, e.g. if there are a lot of high/mid-costs but no/very few low-costs, you can stop iterating earlier

Answer (score 0):

Here i have a struct array option code you can modify for your 3d value array. Here I used the struct function to work this program.

```
struct item
{
    double w,p,u;
};
```

you can use

```
//Fractional Knapsack
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct item
{
    double w,p,u;
};
bool compare( item a, item b)
{
    return a.u>b.u;
}
int main()
{
    int n,w;
    item arry[100];
    cin>>n>>w;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>arry[i].w>>arry[i].p;
        arry[i].u = arry[i].p/arry[i].w;
    }
    sort(&arry[0],&arry[n],compare);
    int p=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(w>arry[i].w)
        {
            p=p+arry[i].p;
            w=w-arry[i].w;
        }
        else{
            p=p+w*arry[i].u;
            w=0;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Total Profit: "<<p<<endl;
}
```